# Spotify Web Api returns doubled results for artist's album search

Tags: spotify

Maybe someone from you will know why Spotify Web Api returns two the same album for this query?

```
curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3nFkdlSjzX9mRTtwJOzDYB/albums?album_type=album&market=PL&limit=50" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer BQDbbuxaIEbU6cg1PXWXBMNg5Lvvnr01ip7XNyxAzD7zv086fZKmuErUM9SyywIef7PkcomUJOMknjlX6fx0IIum9QgYubDleo0N-A7_UkZMdQ5vJS-Z3pSJrN3PQkS-XFwK3KQXVWY17QtgztYJ1qyUr7WjIsiXSSyLjw"
```

I get two the same albums (first and second) that differ only w available markets. In both cases market I choose in query appears in available markets array. In Spotify Android App I get only one album. Am I doing something wrong? :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do everything good. The problem is in Spotify music database. When you will go to Spotify application and type in search bar "Magna Carta... Holy Grail" you will se also two the same album.

Comment: Indeed :) So how do they do it in app that in Jay's albums I see only one Magna Carta? Do they check album name and if it's the same they display only one? :)

Comment: I don't know how they do it :D I have the similar problem in my application and I don't have any fix for now